# How do you know what development packages to install before compiling a program from source?

Tags: compiling, package-management, dependencies

An example for Python: [What are the packages/libraries I should install before compiling Python from source?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21547/4363)

At this point, the only way I know is to `./configure` and wait for it to stop at errors, try to understand the error, and google the error message to find out which development package to download.

That's inefficient.

Which part of the documentation or code should I look? Is there some standard location?